# Display a View Block multiple times in a region with each view using a different filter

Tags: views, theming

Here's a visual representation of what I wanted to happen.

```
<my-region>

    <article-list-view filter=article-type-1 />

    <article-list-view filter=article-type-2 />

    <article-list-view filter=article-type-3 />

</my-region>
```

Now I can actually just go ahead and create a separate region and a separate view block for each type of filter but it doesn't look like good design since It's going to be repetitive.

Is my goal doable? If not, what's the common approach to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have described, yes.  It is not only doable, it is quite easy.

You can add different pages, blocks or even attachments.  When you creating/editing a view, click on "Add" then select what you would like.

[image: Views]

With an attachment, you can select before, after or both for each attachment.

The key to making this work is to only set criteria for that display only.  In the example below, I am in the "Add Fields" dialog.  If you want a separate filter for this particular page/block/attachment, make sure to select "This Page (Override)"

[image: Views Capture 2]

When you do this, anything in this view will be restricted to this display only.